# HTML Help Viewer does not show the content of .chm file

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 x64.

The Windows Help Viewer (HelpPane.exe and hh.exe) do not show the content of .chm files. This problem occurs when opening a .chm file, starting the Windows "Help and Support" or launching the help from local programs (e.g. Eclipse, Visual studio, etc).

Actions Taken:

- `sfc /scannow` did not report any relevant errors.
- Process Monitor did not show any errors.
- The hhctrl.ocx, itss.dll, and itircl.dll DLLs were manually registered, but this did not resolve the problem.
- The solution stated [on a Microsoft forum](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/dc805621-eb4e-42c5-ae6c-456946e6871a/) does not apply to my case since the registry entry in my computer is correct.
- an Upgrade/Repair install stuck at the middle and failed.
- H3Viewer installed but it also did not show the content.
- Visual studio 2012 Help Viewer 2.0 behaves the same as well.
- MJsDiag.exe was run on two identical systems (Win 7 x64): the results are identical except the following lines:

  ```
  HTML Help Run-time Components

  File Register ** Failed **: C:\Windows\system32\hhctrl.ocx (Version: 6.1.7600.16385)
  File Register ** Failed **: C:\Windows\system32\itss.dll (Version: 6.1.7600.16385)
  File Register ** Failed **: C:\Windows\system32\itircl.dll (Version: 6.1.7601.17514)

  File Found: C:\Windows\system32\hhctrl.ocx
      Version = 6.1.7600.16385
      Registry Info: {adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11}
        ClassName = HHCtrl Object
        InProcServer32 = C:\Windows\System32\hhctrl.ocx
        ProgID = Internet.HHCtrl.1
      DLL is Found and Registered OK = YES

  File Found: C:\Windows\system32\itss.dll
      Version = 6.1.7600.16385
      Registry Info: {5D02926A-212E-11D0-9DF9-00A0C922E6EC}
        ClassName = Microsoft InfoTech IStorage System
        InProcServer32 = C:\Windows\System32\itss.dll
        ProgID = MSITFS1.0
      DLL is Found and Registered OK = YES

  File Found: C:\Windows\system32\itircl.dll
      Version = 6.1.7601.17514
      Registry Info: {4662DAA5-D393-11D0-9A56-00C04FB68BF7}
        ClassName = 
        InProcServer32 = C:\Windows\System32\itircl.dll
        ProgID = ITIR.WordWheelBuild.4
      DLL is Found and Registered OK = YES
  ```

  The DLL files were manually registered but the problem still persists.
- Uninstalling Visual Studio 2012 and other programs did not solve the problem either.

Please note that all the .chm and help files are locally stored on the system and they have not been accessed remotely.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So what do you see when you try to open a CHM, just an empty window?